# How do I turn sound on while using XBMC in full screen mode?

Tags: xbmc

While using XBMC on full screen mode, if the sound is silenced, I have to leave full screen mode and use the sound tray icon to turn sound on. Is there a way to do this without leaving full screen mode on XBMC?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have media keys on your keyboard, you can set a custom keyboard shortcut. Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Sound and Media`. Click on the entry to the right of `Volume mute` and the press the key combination you'd like for the new shortcut. There is currently a bug in the keyboard shortcuts dialog, so your shortcut might not work until you reboot.

Comment: I have Fn + Esc as sound mute on my keyboard, but it only works if sound is enabled before playing some video. If I forget to enable sound on the tray icon before using XBMC and start playing video, sound will not play (I can see the sound level but no sound comes out).